# Qt vs XCB: How powerful is Qt to do low level tasks?

Tags: qt, qt4, gtk, xcb

I'm trying to create a program to lock the screen of a computer with Linux OS which is to be unlocked using my own authentication mechanism. Can I do it in Qt alone( The lock screen, the ability to switch to the lock screen ...) or do I need to learn XCB or something related?

Answer (score 0):

Window or session management like locking the screen isn't covered by Qt. You'll need to use native API.

Usually locking the screen isn't something random applications do, but something the desktop environment offers to the user. Thus covering such tasks in a UI toolkit doesn't make much sense. (Same goes for administration-related tasks, like configuring network interfaces).

Comment: I don't want to use the native lock screen. I want to create mine with different look and feel plus a different authentication mechanism. Can you give me some keywords to start with(i.e. on accessing the native API)?

Comment: I'd look at existing implementations from KDE, Gnome, XFCE, etc E.g., the KDE binary doing this is kscreenlocker. It's part of kde-workspace ( http://quickgit.kde.org/?p=kde-workspace.git ), subdir ksmserver/screenlocker .